# XmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName() does not read enough data

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

**EDIT: Yeah it seemed like my Watch window lagged. It keep presenting the previous result. Did anyone encountered this situation?**

**EDIT: As you ask me for the location I set the break point, it is after the last line.**

Here is my C# code

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(fileName);
id = document.GetElementsByTagName("id");
```

And here is my XML file

```
<StudentList>
  <id>1</id>  
  <id>3</id>  
  <id>7</id>  
  <id>9</id>
  <id>8</id>
  <id>Invalid</id>  
</StudentList>
```

As I try to debug, `id.Count` equals to 4, while I think it should be 6.

Why does the debugger say there are only 4 elements?

Comment: Try to debug it as follows: XmlNodeList id = doc.GetElementsByTagName("id"); for (Int32 i = 0; i < id.Count; ++i) { Console.WriteLine(id[i].InnerXml); }

Comment: What does this have to do with LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Do you get similar results if you use the "SelectNodes" method instead? The MSDN documentation recommends against using GetElementsByTagName.

Comment: on what line is your breakpoint?

Comment: Put a breakpoint AFTER the GetElementsByTagName line, and when you hit the breakpoint, in the Immediate window type: "document.OuterXml" and "id.Count" (without the quotes).

Comment: @Paul Now the `id.Count` gives me a 0. I honestly don't understand what is happening!

Comment: @Zarathos Yeah it gives me a 6? Seem like the Watch Window lagged or something

Comment: @Zarathos Yeah, it gives my the correct result now. Thank you very much. Have you seen a lagged Watch window before? Should I use the Immediate Window instead?

Answer (score 0):

If your xml file looks like you show above you should get `id.Count` equals 6.

Let's try do this:

```
  XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
  document.LoadXml(@"<StudentList>
                            <id>1</id>  
                            <id>3</id>  
                            <id>7</id>  
                            <id>9</id>
                            <id>8</id>
                            <id>Invalid</id>  
                        </StudentList>"); 

   id = document.GetElementsByTagName("id");
   Console.WriteLine(id.Count);
```

In the console you can see "6".

So I think that you set value of `id` before your code that you presented us.
And value 4 is from a previous operation.

Set breakpoint on this line:

```
id = document.GetElementsByTagName("id");
```

And in the Immediate Window you can type id and you will get this result:

```
id
{System.Xml.XmlElementList}
    [System.Xml.XmlElementList]: {System.Xml.XmlElementList}
    Count: 4
```

Next press F10, the code in that line will be executed, you must again type in Immediate Window id and you will get:

```
id
{System.Xml.XmlElementList}
    [System.Xml.XmlElementList]: {System.Xml.XmlElementList}
    Count: 6
```

Comment: I used the watch window when I debug, guess that they will produce the same result right?

Comment: Yes, this will produce the same result. So what happens when you try my solution? It's working? It's produce 4 and 6 ?

Comment: Yes, your solution works well. It turns out that I had 2 XML files with the same name, one with 4 records and one with 6 records :(. Thank you